# Facing several errors while building the project in Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting these errors after importing the android project

Failed to resolve: firebase-core
Open File

Failed to resolve: multidex
Open File

Failed to resolve: play-services-ads
Open File

Failed to resolve: play-services-auth
Open File

Failed to resolve: firebase-auth-license
Open File

Failed to resolve: common
Show in File

I am unable to know the exact reason of this issue. Please check.

**build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha09'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url  "https://adcolony.bintray.com/AdColony" }
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/ironsource-mobile/android-sdk" }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app level build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' version '0.8.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.android"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id : "65f11821-8462-4ec4-9e41-XXXXX",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "916XXXXXXX00"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // applovin
    implementation project(':unity-ads')
    //unity ads
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    //compile 'com.github.cooltechworks:ScratchView:v1.1'//not used
    implementation 'com.jackpocket:scratchoff:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.adcolony:sdk:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[4,5)'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:6.7.0.1@jar'
    //compile 'com.google.ads.mediation:unity:2.1.1.0' //not used
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.1'
    implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'
    //get server time
    //compile 'com.github.instacart.truetime-android:library-extension-rx:2.0'
    //compile 'com.github.instacart.truetime-android:library:2.0' // not used
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.7.1, 3.99.99]'
    implementation files('libs/applovin-sdk-7.7.0-javadoc.jar')
    implementation files('libs/applovin-sdk-7.7.0.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Don't ask duplicate questions. They are likely to be closed as duplicate as you can see above. Instead, edit your old questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: Unfortunately, I've belatedly realized that this question was a duplicate. [Please refer to the answer here instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50749790/android-getting-multiple-errors-while-building-the-project/50779610#50779610) (I'm also leaving this duplicate answer text here for now - although it will probably eventually be deleted - to preserve the solution that the original poster marked as correct.)**

Apparently, [jcenter has started mirroring Google's repo](https://twitter.com/dannyroa/status/1004327241826762752?s=19). Try moving `google()` before `jcenter()` in the `allprojects` section of your project's `build.gradle` (like this):

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url  "https://adcolony.bintray.com/AdColony" }
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/ironsource-mobile/android-sdk" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try another version of this APIs. And you should to declare constant version and use it like {$const} then your gradle will be less error prone about versions difference.